# UnitTestIsolationException: Throws Exception while running Shims test in Release/Debug mode

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to run this unit test using Microsoft Shims, but it throws me exception in `Shims.Context.Create();` method.

**Environment:** VS 2012, Win2K8 R2

```
namespace MyShimsUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyUnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetCurrentYear()
        {
            using (Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                // Some Logic...
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Detailed Exception:**

```
Result Message: 
Test method MyShimsUnitTest.MyUnitTest.GetCurrentYear threw exception: 
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio and rerun this test
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
   at MyShimsUnitTest.MyUnitTest.GetCurrentYear()
```

Comment: Can you please just confirm you did what it suggests (restart Visual Studio)

Comment: @DaveRook: Yes, I have restarted my VS but no luck.

Comment: @skumar: Which test runner did you use to run the test above?

Comment: @skumar -- if you are going to [create a tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sharepoint-workflow/info) and [copy the text verbatim from another source without attribution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35074/SharePoint-Workflow-Basics), that is plagiarism and will be flagged as such.  **Please** attribute the source when creating a tag wiki.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Appreciate your feedback. I will keep it mind & will follow it in future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Shims require runtime instrumentation performed by the IntelliTrace profiler. The test runner is responsible for setting up the environment variables required for CLR to load the profiler as well as providing the list of types the profiler must instrument for Shims. The UnitTestIsolationException is thrown when the ShimRuntime is unable to locate and attach to the IntelliTrace profiler, which it expects to be already loaded by the CLR.

As Jin-Wook mentioned earlier, this problem occurs when the test is executed by a runner that does not perform the required profiler initialization. Test Explorer and the vstest.console.exe are two such runners that ship with Visual Studio 2012. At this time, the Visual Studio test runners do not perform the required profiler instrumentation when running tests in "legacy" mode, which happens when you have a .TESTSETTINGS file selected for your run or a .RUNSETTINGS file that forces legacy mode.

You may be able to use third-party test runners that support profiler instrumentation required by Shims.

Comment: In VS2015 I had to turn off the "IntelliTrace events and call information" option under IntelliTrace Settings or I would get this exception when debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The solution to my problem was to uncheck the selected .testsettings file from the menu: TEST/Test Settings and here the item(s) above the Select Test Settings File.

Comment: Having already turned off **native code debugging**, this fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

It could be caused by not using the test explorer of vs 2012. To use the shim, you should run tests only using the test explorer.

You can use other test framework such as Nunit or Xunit with the shim if installing appropriate test runner for vs 2012. It can be downloaded from the vs extension manager.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too. Thankfully the other answers here helped me fix my issue:

I'm using Resharper and when using the context menu I noticed that the runner is using MSTest. Even when finding the test in test explorer and selecting debug I received the same exception.

I then went into Resharpers's options and under *Tools -> Unit Testing -> MsTest* I unchecked "Enable MSTest support". This unfortunately disables the option to right click on your test and hit run/debug, but it did allow `ShimsContext.Create()` to behave correctly when selecting debug from the Test Explorer view!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your TestProject Properties -> Under Debug section Check the "ENABLE NATIVE CODE DEBUGGING" checkbox.

This is should do.  [image: Snapshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me to overcome the exception.

Answer (score 0):

We saw this error reported by Bamboo, our build server. It was invoking an MSbuild 4.0 task. The unit test work fine on the dev's local PCs. I deleted this bamboo task and created a new task that invokes Visual Studio 2012's vstest.console. The tests now pass but Bamboo is not able to count the number of tests. This is a Bamboo problem not mine.

Comment: To get this to work on bamboo do you have to install VS Ultimate on the server?

Comment: No, it's Premium 2012