# Exception running unit tests with Fakes on build server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, microsoft-fakes

I am getting the following  error

> Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio and rerun this test

I have VS2012 and they run locally fine.  Build server is TFS2012.  I have tried using the DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml and also removing the reference to the test settings file.

I'm running out of ideas now, so any help welcomed.

Comment: Do you have a .testsettings or .runsettings file that might force "legacy" mode?  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17111357/270348

Comment: There is one, but I have removed the line in the build definition that references it (in the build definition - Process\Basic\Automated Tests\1. Test Assembly\ TestSettings File

Comment: Which update and edition of VS2012 is installed on the build server?  Maybe the one installed there doesn't work with Fakes.  I think you need Ultimate (any update) or Premium (Update 2 or better)

Comment: 11.0.60315.1 (Tfs2012.Update2), I think it's professional version, but can't see how I can tell.

Comment: It should be in Help-> About.  i don't think Fakes is available in Professional - only Premium and Ultimate

Comment: In terms of visual studio, update 2 added support for fakes to the professional edition, are you saying you think its different for TFS?

Comment: BTW, I can't find help\about, where is this I should be looking?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38897/discussion-between-robsiklos-and-justin-harvey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the testsettings file - even if it's not referenced, it still affects what's going on (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17111357/270348)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using mstest or the Visual Studio Test Runner?  According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15608129/270348, the latter is required.