# WinDbg'ing Unit Tests C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, windbg, intellitrace

**What's my question/problem?**
I'm trying to use WinDBG to attach to a few of my unit tests, which are in a Class Library (Unit Test Project), but I can't get WinDbg to break on managed exceptions.

**Why am I doing this?**
Currently I have tests that utilize shims and are bumping into this issue:  [UnitTestIsolationException: Throws Exception while running Shims test in Release/Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664814/unittestisolationexception-throws-exception-while-running-shims-test-in-release)

However, this is ONLY happening when these tests are run in tandem (same playlist in test explorer) with some other tests that aren't using shims.  When run individually, the tests pass fine.

So, I figured I'd fire up WinDbg (with my very limited knowledge of it), attach to the test runner, and break on the exceptions there.

**What I've Tried:**
Since this is a DLL it's obviously being loaded up by some executable to run the code within the tests (test runner).  While I *was* originally just running these tests in Visual Studio, I had trouble determining which process to attach WinDbg too, so instead I started using vstest.console.exe to start running the tests, then attach to that.

I'm able to attach fine, and WinDbg halts the execution of the test runner (yay!).

Now, I want to break as soon as a CLR exception is thrown (meaning my UnitTestIsolationException). After googling, I found the windbg command to do so:  `sxe clr`

Then I type `g`, and the program starts running through my tests again.

**Behavior I'm seeing:**
WinDbg never breaks on the UnitTestIsolationException - all the tests run to completion, the test results are printed to the console, then the program terminates:

```
Passed   [SomePassingTestName]
Passed   [SomePassingTestName]
Failed   [TheFailedTestMethodName]
Error Message:
   Test method [TheFaileTestMethodName] threw exception:
   Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationExceptio
n: Unexpected error returned by SetDetourProvider in profiler library 'C:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsof
t\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.14.0.0.dll'.
```

Comment: Could you provide an SSCCE (minimal example)?

Comment: what managed debugging extension are you using? sos / psscor / sosex ?

Comment: @MaLio I'm using sos

Comment: @Thomas I'll see what I can provide, this is coming from a medium-sized code-base utilizing DI and the like so I need to try to break out the relevant pieces.

Comment: Are you sure vstest.console.exe isn't starting a new process to run the actual test? You could use procmon to verify that. I would also try procdump from sysinternals to dump on first chance exceptions. `procdump -e 1 <pid or unique name>`

Comment: I prefer psscor but try !StopOnException  -derived  -create System.Exception

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Excellent idea!  Dug into procmon, determined that vstest.console.exe actually launches two sub-processes:  te.processhost.exe and te.processhost.managed.exe.  Attaching to te.processhost.managed.exe seems to be working :D

Comment: @MaLio with Lieven's idea and your code I was able to get it to break on the exceptions.  Unfortunately, I don't have the PDB files necessary to look much further at this point, so I'll see if I can find them somewhere, if not, I'll have to reach out to Microsoft.

Comment: In a nutshell, you've both really helped me answer the ask here (why am I not breaking on my exceptions), so please add answers, and I'll get them marked appropriately.  Thanks!

Comment: @MaLio - I don't consider my contribution to be in the same class as yours so if you would do the honors of providing an answer, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers thanks ... most gracious of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer psscor but try

```
!StopOnException -derived -create System.Exception
```

Comment: Thanks!  As pointed out in the comments on the question, in addition to this, the process I was debugging was launching child processes, and it was /those/ that needed to be attached to.

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski: So if `.childdbg 1`, do you still need `!soe` or does `sxe clr` suffice then?